# freestyle not rendering open ends

Tags: rendering, mesh, freestyle

I’m unsure if this feasible, but this is what I want to do: In edit mode the lines for the arms are visible but when I render with freestyle these do not get rendered. I think I have a hunch of what the problem is: namely that these lines are open ends so that they do not describe a particular area (see arrows in pictures attached). Is there a solution to this problem? I’ve tried edge marks but it does not solve my issue

[image]

PS. Here is the Blender file: [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question the pointed area of the wrist cuffs is render with freestyle line and the arm is not.

Reason is the wrist cuffs has a fill mesh.

Look this way.

[image]

And the arm line is just a line not filled

**How can you make it fill.**

Just select the verts and Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate little below the line.

Select the duplicate and the above original line and press <kbd>F</kbd> key

Now render and get the Freestyle render

[image]

Comment: OK. Reasonable enough. And it works. BUT. It affects all the shape keys I made (when I animate, the newly drawn lines sort of flickers.